# Finding output values in a circuit with a zener diode in parallel with a resistor

Tags: voltage, diodes, voltage-divider, zener

### Find *Vout* for all possible values of *Vin*. In this problem, *Vf* is the forward voltage drop across the diode and *Vr* is the reverse voltage drop across the diode. (You must break the problem into 3 ranges)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8f5mh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know the ranges are when *Vin* is positively large enough so that there is a voltage drop across *R1*=*Vf*, when *Vin* is negatively large enough so that there is a voltage drop across *R1*=*Vr*, and when *Vin* is between these two ranges. How would you express *Vout* in terms of *Vin* and the resistor values?

Answer (score 2):

The result is going to be a piecewise function.  The basic idea with this sort of a problem is to write out an equation assuming the diode is in each operating mode (cutoff, forward bias, and reverse bias), figure out where the transitions between operation regions are in terms of Vin, then write a piecewise function that selects the proper equation under the proper conditions.